# Am I thinking about the linear regression model correctly?

Tags: linear-regression

I have the following model:

```
<bound method Model.summary of Class                          : LinearRegression

Schema
------
Number of coefficients         : 18
Number of examples             : 21613
Number of feature columns      : 17
Number of unpacked features    : 17

Hyperparameters
---------------
L1 penalty                     : 10000000000.0
L2 penalty                     : 0.0

Training Summary
----------------
Solver                         : fista
Solver iterations              : 10
Solver status                  : Completed (Iteration limit reached).
Training time (sec)            : 1.2776

Settings
--------
Residual sum of squares        : 2842629034369063.5
Training RMSE                  : 364204.5762

Highest Positive Coefficients
-----------------------------
(intercept)                    : 274873.056
bathrooms                      : 8468.5311
grade                          : 842.068
sqft_living_sqrt               : 350.0606
sqft_living                    : 24.4207

Lowest Negative Coefficients
----------------------------
No Negative Coefficients       :
```

Does this mean that my equation would be:

Prediction  = 274873.056 + 8468.5311[bathroom] + 842.068[grade]^2 + 350.0606[sqft_living_sqrt]^3 + 24.4207[sqft_living]^4

If that is correct, then how does the model know which features belong to the power 2, power 3, etc. ? If I change the order of the features will the coefficients change?

Comment: Hi!

It seems to me that you are using Root Mean Square Error, Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, as a measurement of performance

Comment: Thanks for the update! even though it was a few years ago, thanks for taking your time to come back and accept :)  Have a nice new year ! `WISHES FROM SWEDEN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I follow you with the ^2 ... ^3... ^4.. ?
RMSE does ^2 ... ^2 ... ( etc )

This is wat RMSE Does:

#### Root Mean Squared Error

1. Find out the difference between original and predicted values.
2. Square the differences
3. **Sum** all squared differences
4. Take the **average** of the **sum**.
5. Take the square root of the **average**

You can see my example over here as Math SE
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650442/simple-calculation-from-formula-rmse/3843518#3843518

Just, substitute your values with the RMSE Formula. And calculate the RMSE.

Regards,

//Will